# Adding a string to the verbatim string literal

Tags: c#, string-literals, verbatim-string

I have a path that is named defaultPath I want to add it into this verbatim string literal but can quite get the quotes around it.

```
    @"""C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe"" /service /data ""..\Data"""
```

I was trying to add +defaultPath to replace Data. So lets say I have a folder name Data.Apple I want the output to be

```
   "C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe" /service /data "..\Data.Apple"
```

But when I have been doing it for the past half hour I have been getting

```
   "C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe" /service /data "..\"Data.Apple
```

or

```
   "C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe" /service /data "..\" + defaultPath
```

Comment: Welcome Back, Mind if I try to help you again...   This sounds like we are continuing from yesterday am I correct?

Comment: Why don't you save your eyes? Create a function QuoteString() and concatenate them in whatever way you like...

Comment: Haha yeah pretty much! i made good progress last night though!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do it like this (preferred):

```
string.Format(@"""C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe"" /service /data ""..\{0}""", defaultPath);
```

Or like this:

```
@"""C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe"" /service /data ""..\" + defaultPath + "\"";
```

---

The first one uses [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx), which basically replaces the {0} in the first parameter with the value in the second parameter and returns the result.

The second one uses classical string concatenation and what I did there was to remove the double quotes after the last backslash (`""..\` instead of `""..\""`), because you didn't want the quotes after the backslash. You wanted the quotes after `defaultPath`. And that's what this code does: It appends `defaultPath` (`" + defaultPath`) and appends the closing quote afterwards (`+ "\""`).

Comment: @heinst: Updated answer. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I was trying to do the second answer....I just didnt add the second \....why did you add that? Other than that they both make sense

Comment: Why do you say it's 'preferred'? Personally, I find it a bit of a code-smell that `string.Format` is used for concatenation where it doesn't do any actual formatting.  Like most things, it depends...

Comment: @heinst: I assume you are talking about this part: `"\""`? Would it be clearer to you, if I would have written it as `@""""` instead? This adds the closing quote after your path. Without it, the result would be `"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe" /service /data "..\Data.Apple` and not `"C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe" /service /data "..\Data.Apple"`

Comment: @nicodemus13: It depends, you are right. But in this example, I find the version with `string.Format` much more readable than the other one.

Answer (score 13):

So if you would like to take advantage of the string interpolation with c# 6 you could also do

```
var randomText = "insert something";
var yourString = $@"A bunch of text in here 
that is on seperate lines
but you want to {randomText }";
```

Comment: If you want to include literal curly brackets, e.g. when creating a JSON string, you can escape those by duplicating them just like de double quotes. Like so: `string value = "test"; string json = $@"{{""val"": ""{value}""}}";`

Comment: Took me a minute to figure this one out and the comment above helped. Here is a more complete version for reference when having {} in the string for json: `var body = string.Format(@"{{""ID"":""{0}""}}", Id);`

Answer (score 3):

Use string.Format to insert the variable between the quotes:

```
string path = "Data.Apple";
string verbatim = string.Format(@"""C:\Mavro\MavBridge\Server\MavBridgeService.exe"" /service /data ""{0}""", path);
MessageBox.Show(verbatim);
```

It makes it easier to read and to implement, you can replace other portions of the path with variable sections in a similar manner.

If you try to just append the "defaultPath" variable to the end, it will never work correctly, as you've already added the closing `"`.