# Regex for number and opening and closing round bracket

Tags: c#

i want regex that only accept number format with closing and opening round brackets
format like this(091)(022)(2)(123-4567)

This i want to use in C#.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: ^(\([0-9-]+\))+$ but its showing error on opening and closing bracket .error like this "unrecognized escape sequence".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression I would use is this:

```
^(\([0-9-]+\))+$
```

This expression will match all of it, or nothing.

To test a string against the expression in C#, it would look something like this:

```
var str = "(091)(022)(2)(123-4567)";
var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(str, @"^(\([0-9-]+\))+$");
```

Comment: i tried this but its showing error like unrecognized escape sequence  for the opening and closing round bracket.

Comment: @swapnil what code are you using? (note that my string is a verbatim string)

Comment: void Validatetelephone(TextBox textBoxControl) 
        {

            Regex rx = new Regex("^(\([0-9-]+\))+$");
            if (rx.IsMatch(textBoxControl.Text))
            { }
            else
                Response.Write("telephon format");
        }

Comment: @swapnil Look at my example code. You need to use a verbatim string. `new Regex(@"^(\([0-9-]+\))+$")`

Comment: @vjsjones ihave remove the @ from regex.i want to match this regex with the value which is enter in the texbox.

Comment: @swapnil You *need* the @ *before* the string, not inside of it. The @ is used for a [verbatim string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537578/adding-a-string-to-the-verbatim-string-literal). It is not actually part of the string. The compiler treats the string differently.